# Java USB Game Controller Library

Tags: java, usb

Is there a Java library out there to read inputs from a USB game controller, and if so, which ones would be best? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JInput -- http://java.net/projects/jinput

I've used it a bit. You should search on Google for a tutorial.